# Extjs 3.1 grid nesting

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is it possible to nest grid inside another grid row?

I mean, that every row in the upper grid will be expandable, and when it will be expanded another grid will appear?

I don't mean a tree panel though.

Thx.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Use RowExpander user extention and just add a gridpanel to it.

Comment: Thanks man. It seems that it is what I was looking for. Do you know perhaps from where can I download the RowExpander extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can find `RowExpander` plugin under source tree of ExtJS 3.4.x in directory `examples/ux`.